# Nothing will upgrade or update, The following packages have been kept back

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates

I have been trying to upgrade some packages, so I can upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 by running `sudo do-release-upgrade` but it gives me:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

When i try to update/upgrade I run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

but it doesn't work.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Foss is always good with tutorials.....https://itsfoss.com/following-packages-have-been-kept-back/

Comment: Have you installed all updates available?  The message you included in your question implies you haven't & thus the upgrade cannot occur until that's performed. The photo shows packages that are a problem, but I'd also check what PPAs (3rd party sources) you have, as some (such as Oibaf's video drivers) prevent upgrade until they are removed.

Comment: The details in your question are ambiguous. Without line breaks or formatting we can't distinguish commands from surrounding text and we can determine if your syntax is proper.  Furthermore, without the output of each command, we also can't determine the problem. Edit your question to demonstrate this separation, include all outputs of each corresponding command and use [formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#) so that we can understand what you're doing.

Comment: For example `sudo apt update sudo apt upgrade sudo apt dist-upgrade` as it is written in your question is not a valid command. Of course this won't work.  It's hard for us to help or tell you if you need to do something different when we can't understand what you're doing on your end

Comment: BMATV - Do not post screenshots. Copy and paste the text into your question. (The linked photo shows a bunch of `xserver` updates that won't install.)

Comment: xserver-xorg-core/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.12]
xserver-xorg-input-evdev/bionic 1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:2.10.1-1ubuntu2]
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/bionic 1.9.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.8.2-1ubuntu3]
xserver-xorg-input-wacom/bionic-updates 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:0.32.0-0ubuntu3]
xserver-xorg-video-intel/bionic 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1.2] thats what it gives when i check upgradeables @EODCraftStaff

Comment: You were asked to add the details to your question; however you've posted xenial & bionic details ... ie. your system isn't fully bionic.  `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/bionic 1.9.0-1ubuntu1` vs `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics | 1.8.2-1ubuntu3 | xenial           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x`   Please add additional detail to your question as already requested; details in comments are harder to read.  You need to apply all *bionic* or 18.04 upgrades first as message said.  Check for package holds etc.